# Create a customized laravel base Project and install it for future projects

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I install a new **Laravel** project and I have been applied Many changes on it for my own purposes. for Example my custom admin panel design and related css and javascript files.

In addition to, I added some packages that are required on whole project.

Now , if I want to Start a new Project , I must to install a fresh laravel Project and add those files and packages manually again that It takes a lot of time.

Is there a way that I could store this base laravel project on it (for example **Github**) and install it via **composer**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Github to create a private/public repository then when you start e new project you clone that repository and then use `composer install` command to get the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Here are all the steps :

- `git clone xxx.git`
- `composer install` (make sure you have included `.env.example` in your git for the app key)
- `npm install`
- `bower install`
- `php artisan migrate` (if, I hope, you use migrations)
- `gulp`

And you are ready to work on your project.